# Javascript Array Loop through specific indexes in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working in JavaScript native project where I have a huge array with 50k elements (json objects).
When i loop through this array it take a huge time > 2h

```
for(var i = 1; i <= myArray.length; i++) {
// my code here for each element
}
```

So what I plan to do is loop through specific indexes in array:

```
// loop one from index 0 to 10k

// loop one from index 10k to 20k

...
```

Each loop I will make it in a separate process

Comment: Why not use two loops the second one starting at 10k?

Comment: What type of content you are having in your JSON?

Comment: hello @Tristanisginger sorry didn't get your idea. can you gave me an example please

Comment: @gyaneshsharma yaes 50k json objects..

Comment: "each loop i will make it in a separate process..." – Look up Web Workers for parallel processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to loop through specific indexes, would this work?

Using `Math.min` ensures that even when progressing in 10k increments, you never exceed the length of the array. With an array of 24736 items, the first loop would run from 0 to 9999, the second loop would run from 10000 to 19999, and the third loop would run from 20000 to 24736.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < Math.min(myArray.length, 10000); i++) {
    // ...
}
for(let i = 10000; i < Math.min(myArray.length, 20000); i++) {
    // ...
}
for(let i = 20000; i < Math.min(myArray.length, 30000); i++) {
    // ...
}
```

You can even nest these loops to perform actions between each loop, like this:

```js
const myArray = Array(54723).fill();

for (let n = 0; n < myArray.length; n += 10000) {
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.min(myArray.length, 10000); i++) {
      // ...
  }
  console.log(Math.min(myArray.length, n + 10000));
}
```